# Переход в настройки android

Tags: java, android

Я хочу сделать вот что: если нет разрешения на установку из неизвестных источников, открывать их напрямую и как только пользователь разрешит, сразу вернуть в приложение. как такое реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341371/redirect-user-to-unknown-source-page-in-android запускайте и ловите startActivityForResult

Comment: да, это именно то что мне нужно. но вот как узнать, есть ли это разрешение в данный момент?
или же просто в sharedPreferences сохранить, был ли запрошен доступ или нет (но это костыль)

Comment: узнал.
для этого есть getPackageManager.canRequestPackageInstalls

Comment: @AnonymousDeveloper дайте знать если получиться поймать результат вызова интента с ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES. Помнится я тоже хотел сделать "как только пользователь разрешит, сразу вернуть в приложение", но в onActivityResult() ничего не прилетало.

Comment: @ermak0ff у меня все получилось. Результат поймал.
Мой код: 

Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 400);

Comment: @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 400:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Init();
                } else {
                    showRequestPermissionManageUnknownAppSourcesDialog();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

Comment: @AnonymousDeveloper действительно, все получилось. Не хватало вот этой строчки кода `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);`. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 400);
```

А также:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 400:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // если успешно выдано
            } else {
                // если не выдано.
            }
            break;
    }
}
```